# Spilt a element in array by new line and assign object property to each new line without Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to js, and would appreciate some assistance.

Currently, I have code, that takes each 1 element array, splits it by \n and then assigns each split value to the object properties using map. Currently, I am using the `map` function to achieve this, but I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve the same output, without the requirement to create a new array.

Example: (Note that the array comprises of 1 single element, until I parse it with map.

```
var data = [
  'FooBar\n' 
    'BarFoo\n' 
    'FoodBar\n,' 
]
 let headers = {
    BarOfFoo: "",
    FoodOfBar: "",
    BarBarOfFoo: "",
    };

let keys = Object.keys(headers);
result = data.map(s => Object.fromEntries(s.trim().split('\n').map((v, i) => [keys[i], v])));

console.log(result)
```

The output would look like this:

```
result = 
[{
BarOfFoo: 'FooBar',
FoodOfBar: 'BarFoo',
BarBarofFoo: 'FoodBar',
}]
```

How can I achieve this with using a more traditional way without creating a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [reduce & forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve the same expected result.

```js
var data = [
  'FooBar\nBarFoo\nFoodBar\n' 
]
 let headers = {
    BarOfFoo: "",
    FoodOfBar: "",
    BarBarOfFoo: "",
    };

let result = Array.of(Object.fromEntries(data.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  curr.trim().split("\n").forEach((v, i) => {acc[i]=[acc[i], v]})
  return acc;
},Object.keys(headers))))

console.log(result)
```